# Google Analytics API - Retrieving a list of segments for a profile in PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have in the code the procedure that retrieve the list of all segment.

```
$SegmentArray = $service->management_segments->listManagementSegments();
```

I need to retrieve anly segment for the specific segment.

If I use this output :

```
echo "results:<br><pre>".print_r($SegmentArray,true)."</pre>";
```

The list (JSON) is:

```
Array
(
    [kind] => analytics#segments
    [username] => nomeaccount@gmail.com
    [totalResults] => 13
    [startIndex] => 1
    [itemsPerPage] => 1000
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => -1
                    [kind] => analytics#segment
                    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/segments/gaid::-1
                    [segmentId] => gaid::-1
                    [name] => All Visits
                    [definition] => 
                )
    ...
```

How I can filter this data for profile?
Thank's!